# JSDoc: Why aren't my nested objects links (why aren't they click-able)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, documentation-generation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I would think that all members / objects / etc. documented by JSDoc should be their own click-able links; e.g., if I have `levelOne --> levelTwo --> levelThree --> levelFour`, then I should see levelOne on the first page and be able to click my way through to levelFour...but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is my code:

```
/**
    Contains various tools and extensions.
    @namespace App
    */
var app = app || {};


/**
Contains App plugins.
@namespace App.Plugins
*/
app.Plugins = app.Plugins || {};

/**
Contains methods and classes usable within unit-testing.
@memberof App
@type {object}
@namespace App.UnitTesting
*/
app.UnitTesting = app.UnitTesting || {
    /**
    Test methods for the App library.
    @memberof App.UnitTesting
    @type {object}
    @property {object} test1 Property definition.
    */
    PluginTests: {
        /** 
        Test for this or that
        @memberof App.UnitTesting.PluginTests
        @type {object}
        @property {method} innertest1 Property definition for "innertest1"
        */
        test1: {
            /**
            Run another nested test
            @memberof App.UnitTesting.PluginTests.test1
            @method innertest1
            @returns {object}
            */
            innertest1: function () { }
        }
    }
};
```

The "namespace" objects are easily clickable, and are accessible from the home page, but `PluginTests` **IS NOT CLICKABLE (IT ISN'T A LINK!!)**, and therefore `test1` and `innertest1` are not accessible. Am I grossly misunderstanding how JSDoc works?

---

PS: Before anyone starts tearing apart my code with hurtful comments, please note that I learned of JSDoc's existence about 3 hours ago and am very new to this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, can you explain your expected result vs the actual result (print screen can be helpful)?

Comment: @oshnaps Basically, I want to be able to specify that certain non-namespace, non-global objects have their own page to which I can link. I suppose for those types of objects, I can just create a completely separate and unrelated object, and then define an alias and place it on as a link on the corresponding property tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, JSDoc doesn't generate pages for all or an arbitrary property. You might expect JSDoc to generate pages for deeply nested object properties automatically, but that isn't the case. For example, there is an open issue on Github on [making it easier to link to object properties](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/376).

The JSDoc output for the `UnitTesting` namespace in the code you provided looks as following (using the default template):

[image: UnitTesting namespace]

I assume that you expected the property `test1` to be clickable and that it would lead you to a page providing information on `test1` (eg. the fact that it has a method `innertest1`). Unfortunately, that isn't the case.

The way code is documented is slightly related to its architecture (eg. JSDoc provides support for classes, modules, mixins, namespaces, and so on). In my experience, good architecture helps writing neat documentation. The JSDoc template you use might influence how your perceive hierarchy. For example: some templates create a tree of namespaces.

Anyway, in this particular example/architecture, your options are:

1. Adding another `@namespace` for `PluginTests`.
2. Adding a `@property` entry for `innertest1` in the `PluginTests` doclet.

Examples coming up.

#### 1: Add a `@namespace`

Adding a `@namespace` to `PluginTests` would result in another namespace page, specifically for `PluginTests`, and would include the information you need:

[image: PluginTests namespace]

The change to the code you provided is obvious, yet I'll just include the part that changed for the sake of completeness:

```
/**
 * Test methods for the App library.
 * @namespace App.UnitTesting.PluginTests
 * @memberof App.UnitTesting
 * @type {object}
 * @property {object} test1 Property definition.
 */
PluginTests: {}
```

#### 2: Add `@property` for `innertest1`

Instead of creating another namespace, you could document the property `test1.innertest1` in the `PluginTests` doclet:

```
/**
 * Test methods for the App library.
 * @memberof App.UnitTesting
 * @type {object}
 * @property {object} test1 Property definition.
 * @property {method} test1.innertest1 A method.
 */
PluginTests: {}
```

This would result in an extra property table *inside* the description of `test1`:

[image]

#### Side note

You might like using the [Baseline template](https://github.com/hegemonic/jsdoc-baseline) to format your documentation. It's still under active development (by Googlers) and subject to change. One of the reasons I occasionally use it: it's easier to navigate. From the docs:

> An expandable table of contents helps users find what they're looking for. Also, a summary at the top of each page shows users what's documented on that page.

One downside is that Baseline doesn't support the second option yet.